# Angular how to splice from Array with key?

Tags: arrays, angular, splice

I have this problem I push data this way into array.

```
this.checkedList.push({"customer_id" : option.id });
```

How can I splice this value out again? Without key this is working:

```
this.checkedList.splice(option.id,1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the the [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) prototype method on the array to find key for the element you're looking for, e.g.

```
let index = this.checkedList.findIndex((element) => element["customer_id"] == option.id);
```

and then splice the array as you'd normally do.

```
this.checkedList.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Good idea. What is idx?

Comment: If you check the documentation you see that it's just the current array's index. I just forgot to remove it (as it is not used here) before posting the answer and will do it now as not to confuse anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

Since this would be the last value inserted, you can simply `pop` this value out

```js
let k = [ {name: 'John'},  {name: 'Doe'} ];
k.push({ name: 'Peter'})
console.log(k)
k.pop()
console.log(k)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not last value

Comment: Noted, Please update the question with more information about the structure of your component

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an object to the end of your array. Have a look at the following snippet:

```js
// create an array and add an object to it - retrieve via index
const myArr = [];

const newLengthOfArray = myArr.push({"customer_id": 23});

console.log(`Added an element at index ${newLengthOfArray - 1} now containing ${newLengthOfArray} elements`);

const myObject = myArr[newLengthOfArray - 1];

console.log("Your element:", myObject);

// adding more elements 
myArr.push({"customer_id": 20});
myArr.push({"customer_id": 21});
myArr.push({"customer_id": 27});

// use find(predicate) to find your first object:
const theSameObject = myArr.find(el => el.customer_id === 23);

// be carefull! find will return the FIRST matching element and will return undefined if none matches!
console.log("Your element found with find:", theSameObject);
```

Be carefull since [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return undefined if no item matches and will only return the very first item that matches! Order is important!